# How total volume indicator $TVOLI is calculated?

Tags: calculation, online-trading, trading-volume, djia, indicators

The value of dow jones industrial average total volume indicator "$TVOLI" is just about 50,000 , while there are millions of shares traded each day in these 30 stocks. How is this indicator calculated and in which unit its value ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: is my question more related to quantitative finance forum than the personal finance & money forum ?